# Spring boot (2.3.10) security framework Remember me causes error for non secure pages

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Persistent Remember me functionality. It's working most of the times but every now and then it throws CookieTheftException. Even for anonymous pages (where user doesn't have to login). In order to solve this... I created @ExceptionHandler method as shown below to redirect the users to the same page and removing the Session.But the getRequestURL() gives /error url and not the url from browser. I think I'm missing a way to get the original URL or maybe there is some other better way of handling it.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CookieTheftExceptionHandler implements ErrorViewResolver {

@Override
    @ExceptionHandler(RememberMeAuthenticationException.class)
    public ModelAndView resolveErrorView(HttpServletRequest request, HttpStatus status, Map<String, Object> model) {
        log.warn("RememberMe authentication occurred for url={}, redirecting the user to login page, error: {}", request.getRequestURL());
        String redirectURL = request.getRequestURL();
        redirectURL = redirectURL == null ? Attributes.LOGIN_URL : redirectURL;
        if (redirectURL.contains("/error"))
            redirectURL = Attributes.LOGIN_URL;
        clearSession(request);
        log.info("Redirecting the user to URL: {}", redirectURL);
        return new ModelAndView(Views.REDIRECT + redirectURL);

    }

private void clearSession(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            if (session != null) {
                session.invalidate();
            }
            SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
            context.setAuthentication(null);
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.warn("Not able to clear user's session", ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Any idea why request.getRequestURL() call results into /error output. If this is not the right way, how to handle it well. All I want is if there is an issue in the remember me while the user is on the non-secure pages....just clear the user and treat it as anonymous user.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but not sure if this is the "right way" of solving this problem. Putting it here in case someone may find it useful.

*Background:* Spring Security uses **PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices** class for handling the persistent token based verifications. I created my own custom **TokenBasedRememberMeServices** class, copied all the code from **PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices** to it. The code is exactly the same except the class name. In the **processAutoLoginCookie(....)** method, I modified the code where it throws CookieTheftException. Instead I'm throwing the RememberMeAuthenticationException. This fixes my issue, not need to write ExceptionHandler. Below is the code:

```
My SecurityConfig class:
    ..
    ..
    .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/user/403/")
            .and()
                .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                .rememberMeServices(tokenBasedRememberMeServices);
tokenBasedRememberMeServices is autowired to this class.
```

TokenBasedRememberMeServices (only changed code):

```
@Service("tokenBasedRememberMeServices")
    public class TokenBasedRememberMeServices extends AbstractRememberMeServices {
    
    @Autowired(required = true)
        public TokenBasedRememberMeServices(@Value("${app.security.remember-me.key}") String key,
                @Qualifier("userInfoService") UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                @Qualifier("rememberMePersistentTokenRepository") PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository) {
            super(key, userDetailsService);
            random = new SecureRandom();
            this.tokenRepository = tokenRepository;
        }
    protected UserDetails processAutoLoginCookie(String[] cookieTokens, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ...
    ..
    // We have a match for this user/series combination
            if (!presentedToken.equals(token.getTokenValue())) {
                // Token doesn't match series value. Delete all logins for this user
                // and throw
                // an exception to warn them.
                tokenRepository.removeUserTokens(token.getUsername());
                String errorMessage = messages.getMessage("PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.cookieStolen",
                        "Invalid remember-me token (Series/token) mismatch. Implies previous cookie theft attack.");
                log.warn("request token doesn't match with the one stored in database, {}", errorMessage);
                throw new RememberMeAuthenticationException(errorMessage);
            }
    ....
    ....
    }
```